# How to proof the following assertion?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just started to study Discrete Math, so I do not know where to start
Show this assertion:

For all sets $A, B$ and $C$ the following holds:

If $A ∩ B = ∅$ and $C ⊆ B$ then $A ∩ C = ∅$

Teachers suggestion use proof by contradiction

Comment: Do you understand that any element of $C$ is also an element of $B$?

Comment: The verb is *to prove*.

Comment: I do understand that the C is a subset that is not a problem . I need to write a PROOF by Contradiction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use

$$C \subseteq B \implies A \cap C \subseteq A \cap B = \emptyset \implies A \cap C = \emptyset$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it by contradiction then:

Let $x\in A\cap C$. Then $x\in A$ and also $x\in C$. Now, since $C$ is contained in $B$ you get that $x\in B$ and therefore $$x\in A\cap B$$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$$e\in C\implies e\in B\implies e\notin A$$
$$e\in A\implies e\notin B\implies e\notin C$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x\in A\cap C$.  Then by definition $x\in A$ and $x\in C$.  Since $C\subseteq B$, then $x\in B$.  We have shown $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, hence $x\in A\cap B$.  Since $ A\cap B=\emptyset$ this is a contradiction.  Hence we cannot choose $x\in A\cap C$ and so $ A\cap C=\emptyset$.